# How do you check the version of a *.ko kernel module in Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

I know you can do:

```
sudo modprobe -v some_module
```

to check the version of `/lib/modules/.../some_module.ko`, but I'd still like to be able to check the version of any arbitrary kernel module that's not necessarily going to be loaded by `modprobe`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

modinfo(8)
     modinfo - program to show information about a Linux Kernel module

Simply,

```
modinfo module-file
```

General tip: At the bottom of a manpage and there is a section called "See Also". For modprobe, it lists modinfo. That section can be extremely useful.

Comment: Hm, better than strings ;) +1

Comment: Curious why this doesn't work for me. It complains it can't find the file even though I checked it exists.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
strings some_module.ko | grep vermagic
```

Or use as mentioned by [Ian Kelling](https://serverfault.com/users/1682/ian-kelling) modinfo.

Comment: I need this on a system without 'modinfo', so this was a good tip.  For me, the command 'strings some_module.ko | grep version' actually returned the version of my module.